# Why only use babel.config.js can compile node_modules

Tags: babeljs

[babel.config.js use case](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/configuration#what-s-your-use-case)

In Babel@next Website, I see if I want to compile `node_modules`, I should use `babel.config.js` not `.babelrc` to config babel.
And I have a try, If I using `.babelrc` with the latest babel@7.x, I can't compile `node_modules` to ES5 even I include `node_modules` in webpack config file, So, I'm confused why so design. The documention have no more explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because they changed on babel@next so people can do conditions with processd.env.NODE_ENV. Just because of that. You won't be able to use .babelrc